# SQL patindex substring

Tags: sql-server

I have data imported in one column that i need to substring to seperate the columns in a new table.

However, the spacing is sometimes different as you can see in the middle of the rows below with the 1 2 and the 1 3.

```
1460165850 346384100 1 2   88534837 1 4 3

1463404020 347588883   1 3 88846400 1 4 5
```

I have tried the code below but because the 2 and the 1 occupy the same position so when i substring i cant get them into two seperate columns.

```
substring ([column 0],22,patINDEX('%[0-9]%',substring ([column 0],22,3))) as 'column 1',

substring ([column 0],24,patINDEX('%[0-9]%',substring ([column 0],24,3))) as 'column 2'
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If that's the limit of the differences just Replace() the 2 spaces with 1 space?

Answer (score 1):

try replacing the duplicate spaces using below first in the table and then segregate columns:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Column_Name,' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')
```

Example:

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('No duplicate      spaces   here   after     executing      this',' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does not seem to do anything unfortunately, still returns the original table/column with different spacing.